# Why does Ubuntu 14.10 want to remove Grive tools on upgrade from 14.04?

Tags: upgrade, 14.10, grive

When running the upgrade tool (I'm currently on Ubuntu 14.04), I see "grive" as "no longer needed" and "grive-tools" listed for removal.

Why does Ubuntu have to do this? Will I have to reinstall Grive after I upgrade? That's not a major headache for me, but I just don't see why it should be listed as no longer needed and to be removed.

Comment: Did you install grive by means of a ppa? PPAs are automatically disabled during a version upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package installed are in two categories: manually installed and automatically installed. Most package that come preinstalled with Ubuntu and packages that you point to install with `apt-get` are *manually installed.* Dependencies of those packages that you did not list manually are *automatically installed.*
In your case, I guess, those packages come as dependencies to some package, that after upgrade that package does not list them as mandatory dependencies anymore. *Automatically installed* packages that nobody depends on anymore are called *orphaned* and are to be deleted on occasion.
To manually mark package as *manual* just `apt-get install it`. It will not do any actual difference to the system.